# CMFCMenuBar and TestStack.White win.MenuBar is null

Tags: mfc, white-framework

I'm trying to use TestStack.White to Automated an MFC Application (for UI testing purposes)

When using TestStack.White with an MFC Application written with CMFCMenuBar (the later Docking framework MFC) I noticed that code like the following fails due to window.MenuBar being null

```
var menu = window.MenuBar.MenuItem("Window");
menu.Click();
```

I know I can overcome this issue with the following

```
TestStack.White.UIItems.MenuItems.Menu windowMenu = win.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.MenuItems.Menu(SearchCriteria.ByText("Window"));
windowMenu.Click();
```

But what I really want to do is get the ChildMenus so that I can check the list of windows open in the window menu, but the windowMenu.ChildMenus is empty

I am pretty sure this is because the menu is really a toolbar/toolstrip (dockable)

Does anyone know how to get the menu items (Tile,Cascale,Window1....) from the Window Menu

Has anyone else seen this issue or found a work around?

Thanks in advance

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the MFC feature pack menu is really a toolbar with buttons. And it is fulfilled using a different process compared to the old style menu.

In your `CFrameWndEx` derived class, for getting the menu bar you can do:

```
CMFCMenuBar *pMenuBar= m_Impl.GetMenuBar();
```

Then it depends on what to do with it. For example, if you want to get the CMenu object that constitutes the menu bar you can do:

```
CMenu* pMenu= pMenuBar->GetMenu();
```

If you want to remove some of the menus, you can do (Notice the reverse order):

```
pMenuBar->RemoveButton(4);
pMenuBar->RemoveButton(3);
```

You can not get the menu the typical way by `YourCFrameWndExDerivedClass::GetMenu()` because these new MFC Feature Pack classes intentionally do `SetMenu(NULL)` when initializing the main frame, as you can see in the call stack:

[image]

I am not absolutely sure, but I think you won't also be able to do the override `YourCFrameWndExDerivedClass::OnInitMenu()` as you could in the old style menus. But you can still use the `YourCFrameWndExDerivedClass::OnInitMenuPopup()` overrride.